# Syntax error when setting up test suite for JUnit 4

Tags: java, testing, syntax, junit, suite

In order to test with Junit 4, I manage to setup the test suite like the following

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)

@SuiteClasses( { ClazzToTestA.class, ClazzToTestB.class })
```

But I keep getting curve underline for those lines starts with @
saying "syntax error on tokens, delete those tokens"

The following is my entire code:

```
package org.dale.testscript;

import net.sourceforge.jwebunit.junit.WebTester;



import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses( { ClazzToTestA.class, ClazzToTestB.class })



public class JWebUnitTest extends WebTester {

    public JWebUnitTest(String name) {

    }

    public void testsetUp() {
        System.out.println("setup");
        getTestContext().setBaseUrl("http://ser.col.com/myportal/retail");
        getTestContext().setProxyAuthorization(null, null, "spxyapp.col.com.au", 8080);
        System.out.println("setup done");
    }


    public void testSearch() {
        System.out.println("enter testSearch()");
        setTextField("userid", "user");
        System.out.println("enter userid");
        setTextField("password", "password1");
        System.out.println("enter password");
        submit("img_submit");
        System.out.println("enter submit()");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks very much

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I copy your code, import JUnit4 and JWebUnit to my classpath and create two (empty) classes `ClazzToTestA` and `ClazzToTestB` next to this test class, it all compiles without errors.

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: um.. i've just change my RAD JRE from 1.4 to 1.5, it's RAD6

Comment: Also make sure you project is set up for Java 1.5+ compliance so annotations are allowed.

Comment: I've checked my project java build path, it's already set to 1.5